# Lyx redefine tabular with tabularx - strange lines

Tags: lyx, tabularx

I tried to redefine the tabular that is used as default for tables in Lyx. The reason is, I want to have an option for 'auto line break in cells'. That you can do with tabularx with the argument 'X'. Example:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
...
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ r X }
    right-aligned foo & long long line of blah blah that will wrap when the table fills the column width\\
\end{tabularx}
```

The redefinition of tabular I use in Lyx looks like this:

```
\let\ORIGtabular\tabular
\let\ORIGendtabular\endtabular
\let\ORIGtabularx\tabularx
\renewcommand*{\tabularx}{%
  \def\tabular{%
    \let\endtabular\ORIGendtabular
    \ORIGtabular
  }%
  \ORIGtabularx
}
\renewcommand{\tabular}{  \tabularx{\textwidth}}
\renewcommand{\endtabular}{\endtabularx}
```

As result I get the following tables (sample lyx file is attached at the end of the post):

[image]

Questions & Problems:

- Why are the tables 0.1 and 0.2 wider than it's content? How do I prevent this?
- How do I set 'X' argument for each cell as default?

[>Minimal Lyx Sample File<](https://www.dropbox.com/s/937u22xj0py2g2p/example_tabularx.lyx)

Comment: Don't do that:-)  `tabularx` works out how wide `X` needs to be then uses a `tabular*` with `X` replaced by `p{2cm}` or whatever, so you get lucky that `tabular*` doesn't call `tabular` which would make you loop. Also you are inserting an unwanted space here `\renewcommand{\tabular}{  \`

Comment: Well is there a way in Lyx to make auto line breaks in corresponding table cells? I don't want to use manual line breaks.

Comment: Go into the table settings and define a width for a column, then text will break.

Comment: I guess this is the best and fastest way to do this. Thanks @Torbjørn